# Magic CSS3 animations not working properly when adding with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, addclass, removeclass

I'm trying to use some magic css classes in some code (http://www.minimamente.com/magic-css3-animations/) and trying to add them with jquery with mouseenter and mouseleave however its not working... at all!

Below is the code i have tried

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#banner-holder').on('mouseenter', function(){
        $(this).find('#prev, #next').addClass('magictime perspectiveLeft');
    });
    $('#banner-holder').on('mouseleave', function(){
        $(this).find('#prev, #next').removeClass('perspectiveLeft');
        $(this).find('#prev, #next').addClass('perspectiveLeftRetourn');
    });
});
```

It triggers the perspectiveLeft, but on mouse out it doesnt do the perspectiveLeftRetourn. Am i making a simple mistake?

Comment: gotta js fiddle of this handy?

Comment: Unfortunately not as it's locally hosted and a work site so i'm not able to post code at the moment. Kinda sucks

Comment: Why do you need `$(this).find('#prev, #next')`.
Isn't `$('#prev, #next')` enough ?

Comment: post you realted HTML codes

Comment: 2 secs guys i'm just sorting a fiddle. And yes you're right .find() isnt needed

Comment: Maybe it's faster anyway , not sure about how this selector works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/PcsNH/6/)

seems to work fine with the following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var els = $('#prev, #next');
    $('#banner-holder').on('mouseenter', function () {
        els.removeClass('perspectiveLeftRetourn').addClass('magictime perspectiveLeft');
    });
    $('#banner-holder').on('mouseleave', function () {
        els.removeClass('perspectiveLeft').addClass('perspectiveLeftRetourn');
    });
});
```

**Edit**: You may also want to remove the class `perspectiveLeftRetourn` when you `mouseenter`.

Comment: i've tried this but it's not working for me -.- i'll debug my code, give me 15 mins :)

Comment: have you got duplicate ids of `prev`, `next` or `banner-holder`? That would cause problems.

Comment: This code still isn't working for me. Works fine on your fiddle but not for me. Also, it only applys the animation once, i need it to be able to do it everytime the mouse is over the banner holder

Comment: Do you get any JS errors? Can you post your html structure. I don't know what else to suggest without seeing more of your code.

Comment: I know mate, but i can't post the code at the moment due to it being work. Leave it with me, i'll see what i can sort out

Comment: While im sorting this, can you help out with making it do it each time? And no, no js errors

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/andyjh07/PcsNH/5/ i've updated the code to look similar to what im using. When you hover over banner-holder the prev and next are meant to have the animation added to them

Comment: i was using the .min version of magic and it was cocking up my animations. Its working better now im using the full version however it is now literally only the issue of making the animation happen more than one :)

Comment: just updated the fiddle/answer. http://jsfiddle.net/PcsNH/6/ it's not perfect if you mouse in/out quickly, but at least it does it more than once :)

Comment: perfect mate, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#banner-holder').hover( function(){
        $('#prev, #next').addClass('magictime perspectiveLeft');
    },function(){
        $('#prev, #next').removeClass('perspectiveLeft');
        $('#prev, #next').addClass('perspectiveLeftRetourn');
    });
});
```

Maybe this will work better.